# Getting inconsistent results

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR 4.6 and I was trying to do some clean up on my grammar and ended up breaking it. I found out that it's because I had made the following change that I assumed would have been equivalent. Can someone explain why they are different?

**First try**

```
DIGIT : [0-9] ;
LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
ident : ('_'|LETTER) ('_'|LETTER|DIGIT)* ;
```

**Second try**

```
DIGIT : [0-9] ;
LETTER : [a-zA-Z_] ;
ident : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
```

**Both produce different results than this**

```
DIGIT : [0-9] ;
LETTER : [a-zA-Z_] ;
IDENT : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In both your tries you changed your ident rule from a lexer rule to a parser rule since you wrote it in lower case and since it's the only difference from the second try I assume that's the problem. The lexer rules are for defining tokens for parsing, parsing rules define the way you construct your AST. Beware that making changes like that can result in great differences in the way the your AST is constructed.